# In Typescript how can I initialize class properties from values array?

Tags: class, typescript, initialization

I have a constructor that looks like

```
constructor(values: Object = {}) {
        //Constructor initialization
        Object.assign(this, values);
    }
```

but it requires named initialization :

```
new Inventory({ Name: "Test", Quantity: 1, Price: 100 })
```

can it be done directly from array like this:

```
new Inventory(["Test",1,100])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var [Name, Quantity, Price] = ["Test", 1, 100];
new Inventory({Name, Quantity, Price});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change constructor to:

```
constructor(name: string, quantity: number, price: number) {
    //Constructor initialization
    Object.assign(this, { Name: name, Quantity: quantity, Price: price });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , but is it possible to use implicit initialization in both cases ,in case of many parameters it's too complicated